# How to remove admin needs for game exe

Tags: windows

My friend is trying to play genshin impact and whenever you open genshin it asks for admin privs but he doesnt have them cause his dad doesnt want him to have them, is there any way he can remove the app's need for admin.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Requests for help to bypass parental, school, or workplace (etc) restrictions are off topic

Answer (score 2):

You *cannot* do that. If the game requires Admin permissions, you must provide the credentials.

You cannot go around that.

So if the game is "needed"  then parents have to give way on permissions.

Comment: Yes. Requests for help to bypass parental, school, or workplace (etc) restrictions are off topic and answers may be deleted.

Comment: Only because it's such a strong CANNOT.  You can change it to RunAsInvoker using appcompatflags to override the app manifest requirement.  It may well do it's own checks as well but you can at some level.

Comment: I changed the emphasis, but I have found that the permission changes described often do not work and  you usually have to be admin to make the changes.